# Change proxy in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Hello I have a code for rotate firefox's proxy and im using it but it doesn't change the proxy.

This is my code:

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy

req_proxy = RequestProxy() #you may get different number of proxy when  you run this at each time
proxies = req_proxy.get_proxy_list() #this will create proxy list

change_proxy = proxies[0].get_address()
print("This is your ip and port: ", change_proxy)

ip = input("Ip: ")
port = input("Port: ")

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

Im typing ip and port partial of "change_proxy" to ip and port and driver opens ip checker website but nothing changes im seeing my old ip:

[image]

and my original ip:

[image]

Sorry for bad english.

[image]

Comment: I added some proxy checker code to my answer, which might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me say that using free proxy IP addresses can be highly problematic.
These type of proxies are notorious for having connections issues, such as timeouts related to latency. Plus these sites can also be intermittent, which means that they can go down at anytime. And sometimes these sites are being abused, so they can get blocked.

I haven't used the Python package `http_request_randomizer` before and I noted that documentation is very lean.  I looked at the source code of the package to understand its structure.

Here is some code that uses `http_request_randomizer` to obtain a random HTTPS proxy, which is passed to the `geckodriver` for use.

```
import random
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import DesiredCapabilities
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.ProxyObject import Protocol
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy

# Obtain a list of HTTPS proxies
# Suppress the console debugging output by setting the log level
req_proxy = RequestProxy(log_level=logging.ERROR, protocol=Protocol.HTTPS)

# Obtain a random single proxy from the list of proxy addresses
random_proxy = random.sample(req_proxy.get_proxy_list(), 1)

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

profile_options = FirefoxProfile()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
firefox_options.set_preference('profile_options = FirefoxProfile()', user_agent)

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX

# add the random proxy to firefox_capabilities
firefox_proxies = Proxy()
firefox_proxies.ssl_proxy = random_proxy[0].get_address()
firefox_proxies.add_to_capabilities(firefox_capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', options=firefox_options,
                           desired_capabilities=firefox_capabilities)


# you can either do this
try:
    # print proxy IP for testing
    print(random_proxy[0].get_address())
    # output 
    46.151.145.4:53281

    URL = 'http://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip'
    driver.get(URL)

# Some of the proxies pulled from http_request_randomizer will timeout 
# for various reasons, so this exception is used to catch these timeouts
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("A Page load Timeout Occurred.")
    driver.quit()

# or this.  You can also put this in a try/except block and 
# increase the timeout as needed.
# 
# driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
# URL = 'http://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip'
# driver.get(URL)
```

Here is a screenshot showing that the IP address was used by Firefox correctly for this session.

[image]

As previously stated free proxy can have multiple issue. The code below shows how to use a [proxy judge](https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-articles/list-of-proxy-judges/#:%7E:text=A%20Proxy%20Judge%20is%20a,check%20and%20validate%20proxy%20servers.) to check the status of an individual proxy.

```
import random
import logging
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from proxy_checking import ProxyChecker
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.ProxyObject import Protocol
from http_request_randomizer.requests.proxy.requestProxy import RequestProxy


def random_ssl_proxy_address():
    # Obtain a list of HTTPS proxies
    # Suppress the console debugging output by setting the log level
    req_proxy = RequestProxy(log_level=logging.ERROR, protocol=Protocol.HTTPS)

    # Obtain a random single proxy from the list of proxy addresses
    random_proxy = random.sample(req_proxy.get_proxy_list(), 1)

    return random_proxy[0].get_address()


def get_proxy_address():
    proxy_address = random_ssl_proxy_address()
    checker = ProxyChecker()
    proxy_judge = checker.check_proxy(proxy_address)
    proxy_status = [value for key, value in proxy_judge.items() if key == 'status']

    if proxy_status[0]:
        return proxy_address
    else:
        print('Looking for a valid proxy address.')

        # this sleep timer is helping with some timeout issues
        # that were happening when querying
        sleep(randint(5, 10))

        get_proxy_address()


random_ssl_proxy = get_proxy_address()
print(f'Valid proxy address: {random_ssl_proxy}')
# output
Valid proxy address: 98.116.152.143:3128
```

Please note that the [proxy_checker](https://github.com/pro100git/proxy_checker) Package that I used doesn't have any embedded error handling, so you will have to add some to catch some of the errors.

Comment: Hello! I tested your code about 20 times but page is not loading :( and i found another code but it is for "chrome" and it works but i need do it on geckodriver cuz my chromedriver is so slow. I putted the error to ask.

Comment: Like I stated in my answer some free proxies will not work correctly.   I just ran the code again and got this proxy `
96.9.69.164:53281` .  When I crossed referenced this proxy it was offline and has been so for sometime.

Comment: When I ran another test this address was selected `119.81.189.194:80` which also didn't work.  Additional code would have to be added to validate each proxy's status.

Comment: Hi, i tested code again like 100 times but it doesn't launch link again. i tried another code for chromedriver and it worked in first start. I think proxies have not problem. Please help how can i fix thissssssss. Thank you...

Comment: The proxies are the issue, because some of these will timeout.  You can add a driver timeout, which might help.  I will update my answer to use one.

Comment: Also im see this on code: firefox_proxies.ssl_proxy = random_proxy[0].get_address()
is it for ssl? i can see http and ftp too in other codes.

Comment: I only tested for HTTPS or SSL in my code, because I wanted by sessions to be encrypted.  Additional testing will be required to determine how the other protocols work with the `geckodriver` and  `http_request_randomizer`.

Comment: BTW What is your use case for using a proxy with FTP?